# Getting content from last element using BeautifulSoup find_all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the content from the last div in in a list created by find_all.

`post_content = soup.find_all('div',{'class': 'body_content_inner'})`

stores the following text:

```
[<div class="body_content_inner">
 post #1 content is here
 </div>, <div class="body_content_inner">
 post #2 content is here
 </div>]
```

I'd like to extract the text that is stored within the last div tag but I am unsure how to iterate through `post_content`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
last_div = None
for last_div in post_content:pass
if last_div:
    content = last_div.getText()
```

And then you get the last item of post_content.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works great and helps isolate just the last div. How would I extract the text `post #2 content is here` from `last_div`?

Comment: @66Mhz you can use `getText()` to extract the text :-)

Comment: This does get us from point A to B, however people like one-liners. Look at Padraic Cunningham's answer.

Answer (score 48):

```
html = """
<div class="body_content_inner">
 post #1 content is here
 </div>, <div class="body_content_inner">
 post #2 content is here
 </div>
  """
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.find_all("div")[-1].get_text()
post #2 content is here
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This works great, I just had to change `get_text()` to `getText()`

Comment: @66Mhz, no worries, probably a different version to my bsoup