# Open Search Results using Selenium- PYTHON

Tags: python, selenium

I can't seem to make it work. The code runs with no errors but it won't open the browser and won't ask me what I want to search.

```py
import bs4, sys, webbrowser, requests
print('searching')
request= requests.get('https://google.com/search?q=' +''.join(sys.argv[1:]))
request.raise_for_status()

#TODO: Retrieve top search links.
link = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.text,'html.parser')

#TODO: Open a browser tab for each result
tabs = link.select("package-snippet")          #apparently most search results
openTabs = min(3, len(tabs))                    #have class package-snippet

for i in range(openTabs):
    openurl = 'https://lazada.com.ph' + tabs[i].get('href')
    print('Opening' ,openurl)
    webbrowser.open(openurl)
```

Comment: Do you want to get the urls of all the listings on the page?

Answer (score 0):

All the links are stored within `a` tags that are under `div` tags of class `g`, so you have to search for the links there. Plus, you should also add headers to your request to get a proper response. Here is the full code to do it:

```
import bs4, sys, webbrowser, requests
print('searching')
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0'}

request= requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk035IfRJXml1sfsMosuriaSJZf-8-g%3A1602743090454&source=hp&ei=MuuHX7HrGKPSz7sPwpWY8Ag&q=find+the+last+child+in+beautifulsoup&oq=find+&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgQIIxAnMgQIIxAnMgQIIxAnMggIABDJAxCRAjIFCAAQkQIyBQgAELEDMgUIABCxAzIFCAAQsQMyAggAMgIIADoECAAQQzoICAAQsQMQgwE6BQguELEDOgsILhCxAxDHARCjAjoNCAAQsQMQgwEQyQMQQzoCCC5QkjZY3jpgkFFoAHAAeACAAYoBiAG7BJIBAzEuNJgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab', headers = headers) #I have hardcoded the url. U can provide the url that u want.

request.raise_for_status()

#TODO: Retrieve top search links.
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.text,'html.parser')

divs = soup.find_all('div',class_ = "g")
url_lst = []

for div in divs:
    a = div.find('a')
    url_lst.append(a['href'])

print(url_lst)

for url in url_lst:
    webbrowser.open(url)
```

Output:

```
['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496999/getting-content-from-last-element-using-beautifulsoup-find-all', 'https://linuxhint.com/find_children_nodes_beautiful_soup/', 'https://www.kite.com/python/examples/4422/beautifulsoup-find-all-children-of-an-element', 'http://carrefax.com/new-blog/2018/9/5/find-child-elements-using-beautifulsoup', 'https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/python-web-scraping-beautiful-soup/', 'https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/', 'https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/php/beautiful+soup+find+children', 'https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/swift/python+beautifulsoup+find+all+child', 'https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/52980821.html', 'https://gist.github.com/yoki/b7f2fcef64c893e307c4c59303ead19a']
```