# Extract text from html tags when there is two or more equal tags

Tags: python

I have this string:

```
'<p><img src="https://a.ltrbxd.com/r..." /></p> <p>Prime Video (Test)</p>'
```

And I want to get just the text between the last p tags.

```
Prime Video (Test)
```

Any ideas of how can I do that?

Comment: you use a HTML parsing library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496999/getting-content-from-last-element-using-beautifulsoup-find-all

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'll take a look at it @FranzKurt